# How can we edit xml files on network places?

Tags: c#-2.0

How can we access xml files which are stored on network places?

Comment: You will have to be a bit more specific than that.

Comment: Do you get an error in doing so? If yes, which? It goes without saying that you need the correct permissions on the network share.

Comment: yes i am getting the following error
"The Remote Server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

Answer (score 0):

Well, either you `net use` the network drive...or you use the direct path `\\yourRemoteComputer\yourSharedFolder\the.xml`.

**Edit:** And also have a look at the `System.XML`-Namespace.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do with that XML ?

You have two options:

- if you're on .NET 3.5 or higher, you can use Linq-to-XML to easily and nicely parse and handle the XML. Doesn't make any difference whether it's a local file or on a network share (assuming you have sufficient privileges to read from that network share)
- if you're on .NET 1.x/2.x/3.0, you can use the `XmlDocument` interface to load and process the XML

You would be writing code something like this:

```
string fileName = @"\\server\share\TheFile.xml";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(fileName);

// do something with your XML

// possibly: save the XML back again? Possibly to a new file name? 
doc.Save(fileName);
```

You're question is very broad and unclear and not very specific, so we can't really give you much help here.....

UPDATE:

> yes i am getting the following error
>   "The Remote Server returned an error:
>   (401) Unauthorized."

Well the error says it all : you are not authorized to read that file, meaning: you don't have the necessary rights to read that file. You need to get those rights before you can do anything else. 
Marc

Comment: My XML Document is on "My network Places" and i am using .net 2.0. my document URL is "http://sapdev:2222/CR/MC/Form1.xml". 
I have used xmldocument also but it is also giving me error like "The Remote Server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

Comment: how can i get permissions for folders which are in "Net Work Places"

Comment: talk to your network administrator - that's not something we can help you with, nor something you can solve in code.